# Error: Declaration of Auth_ORM_Driver in Kohana 2.3.4

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I moved a Kohana website of mine to another webserver and I'm getting this error:

> modules/auth/libraries/drivers/Auth/ORM.php [12]: Declaration of
>   Auth_ORM_Driver::complete_login() should be compatible with that of
>   Auth_Driver::complete_login()

I'm using `Kohana 2.3.4` and `PHP 5.3.3`.

The system was running perfect in the previous server, and in the new server there's already an old website version running perfectly (same system and same kohana version).

Any clue about what the problem might be? Maybe a problem when transferring the files or perhaps a permission issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means your new server has strict error reporting on so it's complaining about the method parameters/arguments defined in subclass `Auth_ORM_Driver` not being the same as in `Auth_Driver`. Two solutions in this case;

- change error reporting level to not complain about this OR
- change `Auth_ORM_Driver::complete_login()` to accept `$user` param without `User_Model` type requirement in front of it